# Will a new WordPress install on my subdomain overwrite everything on the domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, multisite

I have a website (http://neabors.com) hosted at BlueHost, and I have created the subdomain, news.neabors.com (it's not published yet). The original site is a social network, and the news subdomain is going to be, well...news. I want a completely different theme/plugin setup, so I thought I should install WordPress separately on the subdomain.

Well, I get to the installation guide, and I'm supposed to check this box:

[image: Domain Overwrite Files]

I'm not going any further because I don't want to break my site. I've put too much work and money into this thing.

I understand how to edit my wp-config.php file by adding

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

and I'm aware that I may need to edit my .htaccess file.

My main question is what should I do, install Multisite on my single WordPress installation, or am I misinterpreting what that warning is saying and it's ok to make a fresh install on the subdomain?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subdomain from cPanel (Which I think you've already done). While creating a subdomain, you'll be able to choose a directory (That also you might've already done).

Now you can go ahead and install WordPress on your subdomain, you don't need to worry! While installing WordPress, you can choose the directory, and obviously you'll choose a new directory.

Comment: When I created the subdomain, it created a "news" directory inside my single public_html directory. Inside that directory is the default .htaccess, 404.shtml, favicon.ico, etc etc that comes with BlueHost. Did I put it in the right spot?

Comment: @IRGeekSauce Yes, you did it right. Now, during the WordPress installation for 'news' subdomain, choose the 'news' directory and you're good to go!

Comment: I came back to accept your answer since it did indeed work. Now I have to figure out why my domain is https, but my subdomain is not, even though I purchased the package to cover it. If I don't figure it out I may be coming back with another question. Thanks for your help!